# Why is my ViewGroup clipping not working on Nexus 7?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I guess I am not clear on how Android invalidation of dirty areas works. I have a custom component meant to represent a fanned hand of cards. The cards are rotated views. The views can be "discarded" by being swiped up or down.

Cleanup (during and after the swipe motion) works well when the views are not rotated, but when they are rotated they don't seem to clean up properly. (See screenshot were the last 4 cards have been swiped up and down, but not fully discarded... This only happens for me on the Nexus 7 not on the Droid DNA.)
[image: Nexus screenshot]

What must be done to ensure that these areas clean up properly? Thanks for considering this issue.